# Fetching nodes with a label and index using cypher

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I want to fetch node and its information using label and index using cypher query but still i get null value in variable "result" in CypherQuery() method.

NewCypherQuery.java (bean)

```
public class NewCypherQuery {
private static final String DB_PATH = "/var/lib/neo4j/data/";
private static String resultString;
private static String columnsString, nodeResult, rows = "", query;
private static ExecutionResult result;
private static ExecutionEngine engine;
private static GraphDatabaseService db;
private static Node amad = null, pari = null, sona = null;
private static Relationship rel;
private static IndexDefinition inxamd, inxpri;
private static Label amd,pri;

public static void callAllMethods() {
    clearDbPath();
    setUp();
    createNodes();
    CypherQuery();

  }

public static void CypherQuery() {
    try (Transaction ignored = db.beginTx();) {
result = engine.execute("MATCH (m:inxamd)-->(n:inxpri) USING INDEX m:inxamd(name)     USING INDEX n:inxpri(name) WHERE m.name = 'Amad' AND n.name= 'Pari' RETURN m");
        for (Map<String, Object> row : result) {
            resultString = engine.execute("MATCH (m:inxamd)-->(n:inxpri) USING INDEX m:inxamd(name)  USING INDEX n:inxpri(name) WHERE m.name = 'Amad' AND n.name= 'Pari' RETURN m").dumpToString();
        System.out.println(resultString);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private static void setUp() {
    try {
        db = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_PATH);

        try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {
            engine = new ExecutionEngine(db);
            Schema schema = db.schema();
            inxamd = schema.indexFor(amd).on("name").create();
            inxpri = schema.indexFor(pri).on("name").create();
            tx.success();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void createNodes() {
    try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx();) {

        amad = db.createNode();
        amad.setProperty("name", "Amad");
        amad.setProperty("age", 24);
        amad.setProperty("edu", "mscit");

        pari = db.createNode();
        pari.setProperty("name", "Pari");
        pari.setProperty("age", 20);
        pari.setProperty("edu", "mscit");

        sona = db.createNode();
        sona.setProperty("name", "Sona");
        sona.setProperty("age", 21);
        sona.setProperty("edu", "mscit");

        rel = amad.createRelationshipTo(pari, RelTypes.KNOWS);
        rel.setProperty("rel", "friend");
        rel = pari.createRelationshipTo(sona, RelTypes.KNOWS);
        rel.setProperty("rel", "friend");
    System.out.println("Nodes created.....");
        tx.success();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void clearDbPath() {
    try {
        deleteRecursively(new File(DB_PATH));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
}
```

InsertNodes.java (Servlet):-

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws   ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    NewCypherQuery ncq=new NewCypherQuery();
    ncq.callAllMethods();
}
```

index.jsp

```
<form method="post" action="InsertNodes">
<input type="text" name="txtname" value="Hello World !!!!!"></input>
<input type="submit" value="Neo4j World"></input>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't really defined values for the two labels amd (inxamd) and pri (inxpri) and nor have you assigned them to any nodes created.

You can either implement the Label class and assign a name to a label such as "inxamd" or use [DynamicLabel](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-using.html). 
Then, assign the label to your node using

```
amad.addLabel(thelabel);
```

Unrelated to your issue above, a label name is usually a descriptive string indicating what set the node belongs to e.g. Person, Dog
And in most cases you don't need to explicitly provide the index hint ([USING INDEX](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-using.html))